# How to deal with multiple <select> dropdown menus in the same class component that use the same state to pass a value to redux?

Tags: reactjs

This code works fine if the user selects something from each  dropdown menu, but if they forget to make a selection, it will just use the value selected from the previous dropdown menu. Also if they don't make any selection at all and submit, it will obviously submit the default value stored in the state which is "0".

Anyone happen to have a workaround for this? Thanks.

```
export class Content extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: 0
    }
  }

  handleOptionChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }


  render() {
    let snowboardItems = this.props.snowboards.map((board,index) => {
      return <div><form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <li key={index} className="list_item">
             <div className="content_div1">
             <h3>{board.name}</h3>
             <h3>$ {board.price}</h3>
             <h4>{board.terrain}</h4> 
             <h4>Shape: {board.shape}</h4>
             <p>Board Length:</p>    
      <select value={this.state.selectedOption} onChange={this.handleOptionChange}>
      {board.length.map((item, index) =>     
            <option value={item} key={index}>{item}</option>     
      )}
      </select> cm
      </div>
      <div className="content_div2">
      <button className="content_button" type="submit" onClick={() => this.props.addToCart({board}, this.state.selectedOption)}>Add to Cart</button>
      <img className="image" src={board.imageurl} />
      </div>
      </li>
      </form>
      </div>

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a case where you should separate this into two components: one to render the list of items (you could do this in the parent passing the props too), and another to render the item and possibly handle its state.

If for some reason you can't though, you'll probably want to separate each board option into its own property on state. Here's an example where state is updated dynamically:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/snowboards-pl9r5

You should always code defensively, so in the example there's a "short circuit" check to make sure that a length was selected before adding it to the cart. Also the select field is marked as required so that you can use HTML5 as another fallback validator.

You can check it by trying to add an item without a length and also selecting different options and adding them to the cart (logging them in the console).

On another note: I changed it to more specific keys because mapping multiple lists and using the index as a key will result in duplicate keys. Keys are how react knows which item is which, and you don't want to confuse react!

P.S. Way to bum me out giving a snowboard example in the summer! lol Happy hackin'